# remove total excl tax in checkout, order invoice emails in magento2

Tags: magento2, tax, shopping-cart, order-summary, checkout-summary

In Store > Configuration > Shopping Cart Display Settings I set next configuration: [image]

But in checkout and cart, order total incl. and excl. tax both are displayed.

[image]

How I can remove total exclude tax from checkout page and order invoice emails?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the below store configuration will solve this.

[image]

Which renders the totals as below

[image]

`./vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/templates/checkout/grandtotal.phtml`
In this file, the totals INCL and EXCL both loaded only when this condition is satisfied.

```
<?php if ($block->includeTax() && $block->getTotalExclTax() >= 0):?>
```

And the includeTax() method check the above-described store configuration value. Switch this "Include Tax in Order Total" to NO in both

`Store > Configuration > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings = NO`

`Store > Configuration > Tax > Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings = NO`

Answer (score 0):

in the checkout cart tax total template, both are included if you choose to display incl. tax (had the same problem).

You have to override the html template file for the grand total in:

```
your-theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total.html
```

inside the original file https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total.html#L16, there is a knockout js if condition `isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal`

just remove the second tr output (class="grand totals excl")

Comment: Tried you suggestion and cleared the cache and did magento setup:static-content:deploy and subtotal is still showing up.

Comment: There is also this file which displays the data and should probably be overriden: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html.